# "Reality Winner pleaded guilty in June". Why is an adjective "guilty" following a verb "plead"?

Tags: sentence-structure, adjectives, syntax

I have read this sentence in a newspaper

> Reality Winner pleaded guilty in June to a single count of
>   transmitting national security information.

*[Handout via Reuters]*

Why is an adjective "guilty" following a verb "plead"?

Comment: There's no reason an adjective can't follow a verb:  I *saw red*, I *heard loud* music, I *thought hard*, etc.

Comment: Ex: A right sentence, I saw a red pen

Comment: "I saw red" is an idiom with its own distinct meaning, "I thought hard" (hard is an adverb) and "I heard loud" is an incomplete sentence, you need a noun (music, noises, talking, cries) after the adjective.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, *guilty* is effectively a noun, the object of "plead". Historically it (or at least "not guilty" - "plead guilty" came later) was the name of a plea, so the phrase was really:

> plead 'Not Guilty'

The noun can be used in a very limited set of contexts: beside "plead guilty" you can say "a verdict of guilty".

Comment: Would it not be analogous to *All those in favor say aye*?